# [CIDER]: Can I rack in day 4 if there are 20mm of sediments and fermentation is over?

Tags: fermentation, cider, carboy

Can I rack in day 4 if there are 20mm of sediments and fermentation is over? Just to get the cider in a second clean fermentation vessel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer? Yes. In fact, I would move your cider to secondary.  This is also a good time to dry hop it if that's a thing you want to do.